# How did the Sunday Without God light novels end?

Tags: sunday-without-god

I watched the anime and I really enjoyed it.  However, it didn't have a conclusive end, rather, it seemed to end in the middle of Ai's journey to save the world.  Seeing as there is no English translation that I have found (official or otherwise), I have been looking for a summary of the books that weren't adapted and how the series ended overall. Would you be able to point me towards an in depth summary of all of the books (or just copy/paste it into an answer)?

Comment: From reading some Japanese spoiler + opinion articles, I could pick up that Ai dies and continues to live as one of the dead, and she falls in love with Alice, who becomes god (?). Anyway, I think you should take this comment with a grain of salt until someone comes with a better summary.

Comment: Would you be able to link me to those articles?

Comment: Last volume review: http://kenkenmk2.blog94.fc2.com/blog-entry-1654.html, you can find review + spoiler for other volumes from this search page: http://kenkenmk2.blog94.fc2.com/blog-entry-1654.html?q=%E7%A5%9E%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5&charset=utf-8

Comment: Oh dear, while Ai/Alice was pretty much obvious, the rest of what you say is like WTF xD (BTW, can a deceased gravekeeper continue burying people ? xD)